# Why does Google's Geolocation API think that I'm always in Monterey, CA?

Tags: geolocation

After [asking for and getting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643405/geolocating-802-11-access-points-by-mac-address-using-google-geolocation-api) a fancy little program that allows me to turn any 802.11 Ethernet MAC address into a Geolocation using Google's Geolocation API, I am distressed to find out that Google thinks I'm always in Monterey, CA when I use it from one computer, and in Newport Beach when I use it at another.

Here is a revised version of the program that I'm using:

```
<?php
$mac = $_SERVER['argv'][1];                                                                     
$postData = '{
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "request_address":"true",
    "wifi_towers": [{
        "mac_address": "' . $mac . '"
    }]
}';                                                                                             

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postData
  )
);                                                                                              

$response = file_get_contents(
    'http://www.google.com/loc/json',
    false,
    stream_context_create($opts)
);                                                                                              

$response = json_decode($response, true);                                                       
$loc = $response['location'];                                                                   
$addr = $loc['address'];                                                                        

echo "Geolocate $mac:\n";                                                                       
echo $addr['street'],"\n";                                                                      
echo $addr['city'],", ",$addr['region']," ",$addr['postal_code'],"\n";                          
echo "Lat/Lon: ",$loc['latitude'],",",$loc['longitude'],"\n";
```

And here are the results I'm getting:

```
% php geolocate.php 00:E0:6F:90:A1:71
Geolocate 00:E0:6F:90:A1:71:
W Franklin St
Monterey, California 93940
Lat/Lon: 36.600237,-121.894676

% php geolocate.php 00:D0:25:8A:79:14
Geolocate 00:D0:25:8A:79:14:
W Franklin St
Monterey, California 93940
Lat/Lon: 36.600237,-121.894676

% php geolocate.php 00-D0-25-8A-79-14
Geolocate 00-D0-25-8A-79-14:
W Franklin St
Monterey, California 93940
Lat/Lon: 36.600237,-121.894676
%
```

Here is on another machine:

```
$ php geolocate.php 00:D0:25:8A:79:14
Geolocate 00:D0:25:8A:79:14:
Via Lido
Newport Beach, California 92663
Lat/Lon: 33.61891,-117.928946
$ php geolocate.php 00:E0:6F:90:A1:71
Geolocate 00:E0:6F:90:A1:71:
Via Lido
Newport Beach, California 92663
Lat/Lon: 33.61891,-117.928946
```

It makes no sense that *every* ethernet address I try is on W Franklin Street in Monterey. Is it defaulting to something associated with my IP address?

Comment: It might. Have you tried changing (or spoofing) your MAC address?

Comment: My MAC address isn't sent over the TCP connection, so that wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wifi localization and it's far from accurate **when not connected using wifi**. Here you script give my location in the middle of Paris, France and the machine I used is located in the east of Paris and connected by dsl.

See http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81873

Comment: If you consider the position with a large error like +/-8km in my case, yes

Comment: Okay. So there is nothing wrong with my program, just my data.  The MAC addresses I am using are in fact wifi addresses.

Answer (score 0):

According to the question you're referring to, the Google geolocation API works by looking up the MAC address of the wireless access point, not your machine's MAC address. It sounds as if it's simply querying a database they've collected of AP MAC addresses and corresponding coordinates.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's not for my MAC address. I'm using the MAC address of my Wi-Fi router.