# Using google maps geolocation api (wifi lookup) with jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I thought I would give it a go to try googles new geolocation api that can give you your position based on wifi signals.

I i whipped up this short JS code using jquery

```
function testmoj() {
console.log("testmojjs");

var wifiP = [
  {
  "macAddress": "00:26:f2:f7:a7:6b",
  "signalToNoiseRatio": -57
  },
  {
  "macAddress": "58:98:35:57:b8:db",
  "signalToNoiseRatio": -68
  },
  {
  "macAddress": "58:98:35:3c:3b:c9",
  "signalToNoiseRatio": -67
  },
  {
  "macAddress": "00:26:f2:f7:a7:6d",
  "signalToNoiseRatio": -80
  },
  {
  "macAddress": "70:56:81:ca:63:6f",
  "signalToNoiseRatio": -83
  },
  {
  "macAddress": "00:22:3f:0f:84:11",
  "signalToNoiseRatio": -85
  },
  {
  "macAddress": "58:98:35:3a:9f:01",
  "signalToNoiseRatio": -83
  },
  {
  "macAddress": "58:98:35:55:6b:4f",
  "signalToNoiseRatio": -94
  },
  {
  "macAddress": "00:24:17:d5:a7:83",
  "signalToNoiseRatio": -84
  },
  {
  "macAddress": "58:98:35:57:c5:fb",
  "signalToNoiseRatio": -91
  }
 ];


$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MyKeyIsNormallyHere:-)',
    data: { "wifiAccessPoints": wifiP },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("wooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("faaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaail");
    }
});
}
```

But all I get back always is (the error function runs):

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "parseError",
"message": "Parse Error"
}
], 
"code": 400,
"message": "Parse Error"
}
}
```

I dont at all see what i am doing wrong here, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the object `{ "wifiAccessPoints": wifiP }` is successfully converted by jQuery to JSON? If not, then you will need to either manually write the JSON (your object literal looks pretty good but results in a javascript array of objects, not a JSON string), or use a client-side JSON-encode utility, eg. the [jquery-json plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) to create the JSON string from the object.

Comment: Oh yes, you may also be snookered by the cross-domain limitation of AJAX. The accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643405/geolocating-802-11-access-points-by-mac-address-using-google-geolocation-api) suggests that such a request should be made from server-side, not client-side.

Comment: If it were cross domain i should get something else than parse error. But I will try all of this when i get back from sports. You should create an answer with your posts so I can accept an answer if my problem is found.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why the javascript code did not work but i moved it serverside onto .net and then it worked. for anyone wanting to use it here is a howto.
This is just quick test code with lots of crap still left in there!

also I got a 403 for a while because i had forgotten to enable it in my google developer console/api console. just carefully follow instructions on google maps geolocation api's page

```
    public ActionResult FindLocationForWifi()
    {
        Models.WifiAPInformation apInfo = new Models.WifiAPInformation();

        apInfo.wifiAccessPoints.Add(new Models.WifiAP("00:26:f2:f7:a7:6b", -57));
        apInfo.wifiAccessPoints.Add(new Models.WifiAP("58:98:35:57:b8:db", -68));
        apInfo.wifiAccessPoints.Add(new Models.WifiAP("58:98:35:3c:3b:c9", -67));
        apInfo.wifiAccessPoints.Add(new Models.WifiAP("00:26:f2:f7:a7:6d", -80));
        apInfo.wifiAccessPoints.Add(new Models.WifiAP("70:56:81:ca:63:6f", -83));
        apInfo.wifiAccessPoints.Add(new Models.WifiAP("00:22:3f:0f:84:11", -85));
        apInfo.wifiAccessPoints.Add(new Models.WifiAP("58:98:35:3a:9f:01", -83));
        apInfo.wifiAccessPoints.Add(new Models.WifiAP("58:98:35:55:6b:4f", -94));
        apInfo.wifiAccessPoints.Add(new Models.WifiAP("00:24:17:d5:a7:83", -84));
        apInfo.wifiAccessPoints.Add(new Models.WifiAP("58:98:35:57:c5:fb", -91));

        String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=" + BlogConfiguration.Instance.Frontend.ApiKeys.GoogleMaps.Key;

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(apInfo);
        var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json);

        //return Content(json);

        try
        {

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                var response = client.UploadData(url, "POST", bytes);

                return Content(Encoding.Default.GetString(response));
            }
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            if (wex.Response != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Url: " + Url);
                String Resp = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Resp);
            }
            else
                throw;
        }

        //return Json(apInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return Content(url);
    }
}
```

And you would need these classes

```
namespace Frontend.Models
{
public class WifiAPInformation
{
    public List<WifiAP> wifiAccessPoints; //according to google name standard for location api

    public WifiAPInformation()
    {
        wifiAccessPoints = new List<WifiAP>();
    }
}

public class WifiAP
{
    public String macAddress; //starting small letter because of standard in google maps geolocation api
    public int signalStrength;

    public WifiAP(String mac, int signal)
    {
        macAddress = mac;
        signalStrength = signal;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing create a file test.html with the following code (replace GoogleAPIKeyHere with your Google API Location Key):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function sendSurroundingWifis() {
    console.log("sendSurroundingWifis");
    var wifis = '{"wifiAccessPoints":[' +
        '{"macAddress":"00:26:f2:f7:a7:6b","signalStrength":-68},' +
        '{"macAddress":"58:98:35:57:b8:db","signalStrength": -88},' +
        '{"macAddress":"58:98:35:3c:3b:c9","signalStrength": -90}]}';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=GoogleAPIKeyHere',
        data: wifis,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("Working!");
            console.log(response);
            $('#content').html('<a href="http://www.google.com/maps/place/'+response.location.lat+','+response.location.lng+'">Show on google maps</a>');
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("FAIL!");
        }
    });
}
</script>

<button onclick="sendSurroundingWifis()">sendSurroundingWifis</button> <br>
<div id="content">...</div>
```